# Maven goal to move file to another directory

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I need to move the war generated to some other directory with **maven goal**.

I know how to move it to another location by adding configuration in pom.xml but i need to do it with a goal.

Which i can run directly without using pom.xml

like: `mvn jboss-as:deploy-only` deploys jboss with war generated without including any plugin specific configuration in POM.

> Their are some restrictions to plugins which can be used in pom. So need to use Maven Goal only